# Replace method for range

Tags: excel, vba

The range is qualified to the correct sheet. `lastRow` is correct. Why doesn't this work??

```
.Range("H3:I" & lastRow - 1).Replace what:="SUM", replacement:="Subtotal", _
lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
```

Comment: Works for me using a static/literal range.

Comment: Well, I need a variable range XD So my `range` syntax is incorrect...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Rory sum is not replaced by subtotal. Edit: also tried without `lookat` and `matchcase` XD

Comment: @findwindow - are you trying to replace the syntax in formulas?

Comment: Yea, trying to replace sum formulas with subtotal formula.

Comment: I understand you need a variable range.  But I don't know how you're getting `lastRow` (you didn't provide that other than to just tell us to trust you), so my point is that if the static range works, then you can narrow your debugging efforts.

Comment: @findwindow - I am 99.9% sure its not replacing the SUM with Subtotal, because it would result in a bad formula syntax. Since `=Subtotal(function_num,ref1,[ref2]...)` is different syntax than `=SUM(number1,[number2]...)`. Excel is smart enough to know that your replace statement will lead to bad formula.

Comment: I suggest you try it without the macro, doing it manually - I think you might find that, because the required variables are different, it will not allow you to do it manually, and I'm guessing something similar may be happening in your macro.  You may want to first replace the equal sign with something (like [Equal] for example) then replace things in the formula, then change it back to an equal sign.

Comment: Actually, just noticed by doing `ctrl+f` on sheet reveals the match entire cell contents option checked.... now to figure out how to uncheck that.

Comment: Ok... setting `SearchFormat` to true or false doesn't change result XD UGH ;_;

Comment: @findwindow - you already have match entire cell contents to False. See my answer to understand the true cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to change actual formulas with your replacement statement, this will not work because the result will be a formula with too few arguments, with the `SUBTOTAL` formula.

You can test this by trying it manually. You can also test this by replacing `SUM` with `AVERAGE`. In that case, your code will work flawlessly since the formula argument syntax is identical.

If you really want to turn a `SUM` into a `SUBTOTAL`, you'll have to adjust for the syntax difference in your `Replace` statement, or find another way to go about it.

Comment: Oh yea, two different formulas. DUH XD

Comment: Hmmm changing to `what:="SUM(", replacement:="Subtotal(9,"` still fails. I think I need to uncheck the `match entire cell contents` option but HOW Edit: lol stupid. I took off that argument. Works now yaaaay <3

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like:

```
Sub qwertyx()
      With ActiveSheet
         lastRow = 10
         For Each r In .Range("H3:I" & (lastRow - 1))
            r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "SUM(", "SUBTOTAL(9,")
         Next r
      End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah I guess you could also use replace function instead of method.

Comment: @findwindow  yes but my approach needs a loop, which is distasteful.